# Django3: How to display the results of a model function into an HTML template and/or Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

So I have the following Classes one for user and one for "Project":

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass



class Project(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.PROTECT, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, editable=False)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False, null=False, blank=False)
    
    
    def monthlyTotal(self,user):
      this_month = now().month
      return Project.objects.filter(
          created__month=this_month,
          user=user
      ).aggregate(
          sum_total=Sum('total')
      )['sum_total']
      
        
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and my view which is also used to populate the Project Class:

```
def homepage(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        project = Project()
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        total = request.POST.get('total')
        created = datetime.datetime.now()
        user = request.user
        project.user = user
        project.name = name
        project.total = total
        project.created = created
        project.save()
        
        #return HttpResponse(reverse("homepage.views.homepage"))
        return render(request, 'homepage.html')
    else:

        return render(request, 'homepage.html')
```

I would like to pass the currently logged in user to the function monthlyTotal so that it displays on my template. This is what I tried so far

```
<p>Total monthly sales = {{ Project.monthlyTotal(user.username) }}</p>  

 <p>Total monthly sales = {{ Project.monthlyTotal(request.user) }}</p>
```

but can't get it to work, also would I be able to display this field in the admin so you see it when you look at a user admin portal?

Thanks

Comment: You can pass this into context https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.base.Template.render  instead (which would be preferred) or do yourself a filter https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use the objects user

```
def monthlyTotal(self):
  this_month = now().month
  return Project.objects.filter(
      created__month=this_month,
      user=self.user
  ).aggregate(
      sum_total=Sum('total')
  )['sum_total']
```

in the template

```
{{user.project_set.first.monthlyTotal}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So this doesn't cause the page to break, however it doesn't display anything for the logged in user.

Comment: This is good it actually DOES display but showing None, so it seems like it might not be getting the logged in user somehow tough above I have a {{ user.username }}and it does display the username.